# How to add "and" before the last element of a list?

Tags: python

I'm making this program and it requires a list to be printed out, I would prefer if the list were a little more correct. I was wondering if it were possible to add an "and" before the last element of a list to make it look right. Thanks.

```
  def inputEat(self):
        input('What would you like to eat? Your choices are {}.'.format(', '.join(healthItems)))
        Fighter.Health(x)
        if self.health >= 100:
            self.health = 100`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have a function to construct the joined list the way you want:

```
def join_and(items):
    return ', '.join(items[:-1]) + ' and '+items[-1]
```

That is, join all the items except the last with a comma, and then add 'and' before the last item.
(Feel free to add an Oxford comma at your discretion.)

```
>>> join_and(['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma'])
'alpha, beta and gamma'
```

If you want the function to give an appropriate result for a list of length 1 or 0, you could do something like this:

```
def join_and(items):
    if len(items)==0:
        return ''
    if len(items)==1:
        return items[0]
    return ', '.join(items[:-1]) + ' and '+items[-1]
```

Comment: `join_and(['oneitem'])` gives `' and oneitem'`. I suggest checking the length of `items`.  I also recommend `return ', '.join(items[:-1]) + ' and ' + str(items[-1])` so it handles non-string types too.

Comment: @Baldrickk I can see what you mean about a list of one item, but I think think if you have a list of non-strings, you'd map them to string as you pass them into the function, rather than assuming that `str` should be used to convert. [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) only works for string sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Join all the items like you were doing, except the last one.
- Explicitly concatenate the last item with and.

`input('What would you liketo eat? Your choices are {}.'.format( ', '.join( healthItems[:-1]) + ' and '+healthItems[-1]))`